# How to search sequence of bytes in an byte array[] of a bin file?

Tags: java, arrays, swing

I'm trying to code a program where I can:

1. Load a file
2. Input a start and beginning offset addresses where to scan data from
3. Scan that offset range in search of specific sequence of bytes (such as "05805A6C")
4. Retrieve the offset of every match and write them to a .txt file

i66.tinypic.com/2zelef5.png

As the picture shows I need to search the file for "05805A6C" and then print to a .txt file the offset "0x21F0".

I'm using Java Swing for this. So far I've been able to load the file as a Byte array[]. But I haven't found a way how to search for the specific sequence of bytes, nor setting that search between a range of offsets.

This is my code that opens and reads the file into byte array[]

```
public class Read {

static public byte[] readBytesFromFile () {

  try {  
    JFileChooser chooser = new JFileChooser();

    int returnVal = chooser.showOpenDialog(null);
    if (returnVal == JFileChooser.APPROVE_OPTION) { 

        FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream(chooser.getSelectedFile());
        byte[] data = new byte[input.available()];
        input.read(data);
        input.close();
        return data;

     }
     return null;
  }

  catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println("Unable to read bytes: " + e.getMessage());
    return null;
  }
 }

}
```

And my code where I try to search among the bytes.

```
byte[] model = Read.readBytesFromFile();

    String x = new String(model);
    boolean found = false;

    for (int i = 0; i < model.length; i++) {
        if(x.contains("05805A6C")){
            found = true;
        }
   }

    if(found == true){
        System.out.println("Yes");
    }else{
        System.out.println("No");
    }
```

Comment: `"pmdl"` is a `String` (not a `byte[]`).

Comment: "05805A6C" is a String, not a sequence of bytes

Comment: Right, but how should I go to search for that sequence?

Answer (score 3):

Here's a bomb-proof<sup>1</sup> way to search for a sequence of bytes in a byte array:

```
public boolean find(byte[] buffer, byte[] key) {
    for (int i = 0; i <= buffer.length - key.length; i++) {
        int j = 0;
        while (j < key.length && buffer[i + j] == key[j]) {
            j++;
        }
        if (j == key.length) {
           return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
```

There are more efficient ways to do this for large-scale searching; e.g. using the Boyer-Moore algorithm.  However:

- converting the byte array a String and using Java string search is NOT more efficient, and it is potentially fragile depending on what encoding you use when converting the bytes to a string.
- converting the byte array to a hexadecimal encoded String is even less efficient ... and memory hungry ... though not fragile if you have enough memory.  (You may need up to 5 times the memory as the file size while doing the conversion ...)

---

<sup>1 - bomb-proof, modulo any bugs :-)</sup>

Comment: How would I use this? Is this a class?

Comment: 1) You call it from your code, passing in the buffer and the key as parameters.  2) No.  It is a method.  You can put it into a class.  Or you copy the code / method body into something else, refactoring as required.

Comment: I don't understand how to use this. What buffer and key suppose to be?. I only got one byte array[] which is the data from the file (model)

Comment: Buffer is the data you got from the file.  Key is a byte array containing the byte sequence that you are search for.

Comment: Yeah, I got that method working and yes it does work in doing the search. However how can I get the offset address of every match? Also, how to do many search with different byte sequences from top to bottom?

Comment: 1) By modifying the code to print the offsets rather than returning `true` / `false` when it gets a match.  2) By calling the method multiple times.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT** It seems the charset from system to system is different so you may get different results so I approach it with another method:

```
String x = HexBin.encode(model);
String b = new String("058a5a6c");

int index = 0;
while((index = x.indexOf(b,index)) != -1 )
{
    System.out.println("0x"+Integer.toHexString(index/2));
    index = index + 2;
}
 ...
```

Comment: I get an error of "possible lossy conversion from int to byte"

Comment: @Midori_hige check my edit, I tested it with eclipse and worked fine

Comment: It does works, surprisingly. Now, about getting the offset of each finding?

Comment: @Midori_hige: my edit now reflects the indices which the sequence occured

Comment: Bad idea.  Unless you get the encoding right, converting a byte array to a string like that is lossy.

Comment: @StephenC why is it lossy?

Comment: Because for most charsets, there are certain bytes / byte sequences that do not map to chars (unicode code units).

Comment: @Pooya It does prints numbers that seem to be "addresses" but they are wrong. The first and second finding should be 464 and 1996, instead of 457 and 1937.

Comment: @Pooya It works really well. By adding a 4 I get the offset in decimal I need. Is there a way to transform the index into Hex?

Comment: @Midori_hige check my update on the code, now it displays hex representation of the integer

Comment: @Pooya Now it works flawlessly, amazing. Will work on the writing to .txt now ^^

Comment: @Pooya How could I do the search inside "x" but between a range of offset. I've tried using a foor loop but the search keeps repeating.

Comment: @Midor_hige you can initialize index to something other than 0, keep in mind index=2*offset. You can also put another condition in the while statement so if index exceeds the range you expected while condition become false

Comment: @Pooya Let's say index = 180 (as the starting offset in decimal)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/102858/discussion-between-midori-hige-and-pooya).